# retrieving ip and port from a sockaddr_storage

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

I've got a `sockaddr_storage` containing the ipv4 address and port of a remote host. I haven't seen these `struct`s before though and I'm not sure how to cast it into a `struct` where I can directly retrieve IP address and port number. I've tried googling the `struct` but haven't found anything. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's a `sockaddr_storage` struct and not a `sockaddr` struct?

Comment: Yeah, it's a sockaddr_storage struct.

Comment: @Tony: `sockaddr_storage` is the preferred struct to use in newer code, as it supports multiple address families, including IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: In new code it's preferred never to allocate storage for any `sockaddr` structures yourself whatsoever. `getaddrinfo` is the only function you should ever use to create `sockaddr` structures, and it allocates them itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast the pointer to `struct sockaddr_in *` or `struct sockaddr_in6 *` and access the members directly, but that's going to open a can of worms about aliasing violations and miscompilation issues.

A better approach would be to pass the pointer to `getnameinfo` with the `NI_NUMERICHOST` and `NI_NUMERICSERV` flags to get a string representation of the address and port. This has the advantage that it supports both IPv4 and IPv6 with no additional code, and in theory supports all future address types too. You might have to cast the pointer to `void *` (or `struct sockaddr *` explicitly, if you're using C++) to pass it to `getnameinfo`, but this should not cause problems.

Comment: I'm only using C standard libraries; extracting the port from a string sounds painful. If I know in advance whether it'll be Ipv4 or Ipv6, is there no issues with casting it into a sockaddr_in / sockaddr_in6 struct?

Answer (score 4):

To extend an answer above and provide a code that uses `getnameinfo` function, check this snippet:

```
struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
socklen_t client_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);

// Accept client request
int client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_len);

char hoststr[NI_MAXHOST];
char portstr[NI_MAXSERV];

int rc = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, client_len, hoststr, sizeof(hoststr), portstr, sizeof(portstr), NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
if (rc == 0) printf("New connection from %s %s", hoststr, portstr);
```

The result is that a `hoststr` contains an IP address from `struct sockaddr_storage` and a `portstr` contains a port respectively.