# How to retrieve IP and port from a `sockaddr_storage` instance?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, winsock

How can I retrieve IP and port from a `sockaddr_storage` instance with `getnameinfo()` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39816122/12247864))?

When I used `inet_ntop`, it worked like normal, but when I replaced it with the `getnameinfo` function, Windows returned an error:

> Code 10047: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.

```
#ifdef USE_IPV6
int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
#else
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
#endif

sockaddr_storage address;
int length = sizeof address;

char buffer[1];
recvfrom(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &length);

// Error
char ip[NI_MAXHOST];
char port[NI_MAXSERV];
int rc = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &address, length, ip, sizeof ip, port, sizeof port, NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
if (rc) WSAGetLastError(); // Error Code = 10047

// Works
#ifdef USE_IPV6
struct sockaddr_in6 *sa = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) &address;
inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &sa->sin6_addr, ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
uint16_t port_ = ntohs(sa->sin6_port);
#else
struct sockaddr_in *sa = (struct sockaddr_in *) &address;
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sa->sin_addr, ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
uint16_t port_ = ntohs(sa->sin_port);
#endif
```

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks, I've changed the source code.

Comment: It still fails to meet the requirements for a [mre]. Unless you can answer yes to the following question: "can everyone in the world cut/paste the shown code ***exactly as shown***, and nothing more, attempt to compile and reproduce just the error you're talking" -- unless the answer to this question is "yes", this is not a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your issue and was able to reproduce the error you were having.

Reproducible example:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

int main(int, char **) {

  WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
  WSADATA wsaData;
  WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

#ifdef USE_IPV6
  int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
#else
  SOCKET fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
#endif

  sockaddr_storage address;
  int length = sizeof(sockaddr_storage);

  char buffer[1];
  recvfrom(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&address, &length);

  // Error
  char ip[NI_MAXHOST];
  char port[NI_MAXSERV];
  int rc = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*)&address,
                       length,
                       ip,
                       sizeof(ip),
                       port,
                       sizeof(port),
                       NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
  if (rc)
    WSAGetLastError(); // Error Code = 10047

  std::cout << "IP: " << ip << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Port: " << port << std::endl;

// Works
#ifdef USE_IPV6
  struct sockaddr_in6* sa = (struct sockaddr_in6*)&address;
  inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &sa->sin6_addr, ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
  uint16_t port_ = ntohs(sa->sin6_port);
#else
  struct sockaddr_in* sa = (struct sockaddr_in*)&address;
  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sa->sin_addr, ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  uint16_t port_ = ntohs(sa->sin_port);
#endif
}
```

The issue lies in the fact that you aren't setting the `ss_family` field of the `sockaddr_storage` structure.

To fix this, you need to specify the `ss_family` value in the `sockaddr_storage` as follows:

```
sockaddr_storage address;
address.ss_family = AF_INET;
```

Once you do this, you should not see error 10047 anymore and you should be able to print the contents of the ip and port buffers and see the respective information.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms740504(v=vs.85)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket